# Matrix postrotate giving weird behavior

Tags: android, opencv, android-camerax

I have been stuck in this problem for quite some days. I understood that the picture in image analyzer/Image Proxy is rotated from what it is being displayed on PreviewView. So to make it in correct orientation, I rotated it and passed it my OpenCV to get all  the point. For some reason, the image is sometimes being rotated, and sometime its not rotated. Here is my Analyser Code

```
class OpenCVImageAnalyser(
    var openCVImageScanPoints: OpenCVImageScanPoints,
    var onResults: (ScannedImageData)->Unit,
    var coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
): ImageAnalysis.Analyzer{

    var imageHeight:Float = 0f
    var imageWidth:Float = 0f

    var lastScannedImageData:ScannedImageData? = null
    var lastBitmap:Bitmap? = null
    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        imageHeight = image.height.toFloat()
        imageWidth = image.width.toFloat()


        coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){
            val matrix = Matrix()
            matrix.postRotate(image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat())

            val rotatedMatrix = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                image.toBitmap(),
                0,
                0,
                image.width,
                image.height,
                matrix,
                true
            )

            var mat = Mat()
            Utils.bitmapToMat(rotatedMatrix,mat)

            lastBitmap?.recycle()

            lastBitmap = rotatedMatrix
            var cornerPoints:List<Point> = openCVImageScanPoints.getPointsExperimental(mat)
            lastScannedImageData = ScannedImageData(
                bitmap = null,
                modifiedBitmap = null,
                hasBeenModified = false,
                points = cornerPoints,
                imageWidth = rotatedMatrix.width.toFloat(),
                imageHeight = rotatedMatrix.height.toFloat()
            )

            lastScannedImageData?.let {
                onResults(it)
            }

            mat.release()
            image.close()
            matrix.reset()
        }

    }


}



CamerPreview

@Composable
fun CameraPreview(
    controller:LifecycleCameraController,
    modifier: Modifier= Modifier
){
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            PreviewView(it).apply {
                this.controller = controller
                scaleType =PreviewView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
                implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
                controller.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner)
            }
        },modifier = modifier
    )
}


Analyzer and other things:-
    var analyzer = remember {
        OpenCVImageAnalyser(
            OpenCVImageScanPoints.instance,
            onResults = {
                scannedImageData = it
            },
            lifecycleScope
        )
    }

    val cameraExecutor = remember {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    var controller = remember{
        LifecycleCameraController(context).apply {
            setEnabledUseCases(IMAGE_ANALYSIS)
            setImageAnalysisAnalyzer(
                cameraExecutor,
                analyzer
            )
        }
    }
```

I will really appreciate any help.

Tried to rotate the image in Anaylser, but its working sometimes and sometimes its not working.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Questions: 1) do you know under what circumstances would the image being rotated v.s. not rotated? 2) could you remove OpenCV for now, and check if the Bitmap + rotation degrees from CameraX is correct?